# React component tree

Tags: json, reactjs, tree, components

I am trying to get a JSON object representation of my React component structure (i.e. parent : child relationships). I am working on a couple visualization tools as a personal project, and one is a component tree visual, but I can't seem to find a way to access the components in a way that can be mapped and organized.

Comment: Without a lot of context for the problem, have you tried traversing react components by accessing `props.children` ?